# Node js.Not getting value after some time interval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one function sha1, whenever page is in load, sha1 function will be on run , and this should be run after 5 sec.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(sha1());
setTimeout(sha1, 5000);
console.log(sha1());

function sha1() {
    var dt = dateTime.create();
    var ency_date = dt.format('Y-m-d H:M:S');
    var generator = crypto.createHash('sha1');
    generator.update(ency_date)
    return generator.digest('hex')
}
```

Right Now i am not getting 5 sec waiting time . both condition running at same time.

Comment: You want to execute `sha1` after 5 seconds? And currently it executes immediately, right?

Comment: yes  @WaleedIqbal

Comment: your code work fine, only but you have not `console.log` after 5 sec

Comment: **Danger**! `sha1` is old and weak! It isn't generally suitable for anything today.

Comment: so do u want to suggest me any thing apart form that?

Comment: yes @SagarGopale , i am already doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` is not sleep.

Your code does this:

1. Call `sha1` and log its return value
2. Set things up to call `sha1` in 5 seconds
3. Call `sha1` and log its return value
4. 5 seconds later `sha1` gets called from the `setTimeout` … and nothing is logged because you have no code to log it.

It isn't entirely clear what your desired outcome is, but it sounds like you want something along the lines of:

```js
console.log(sha1());
setTimeout(log_sha1, 5000);
console.log(sha1());

function sha1() {
    return "This is an example";
}

function log_sha1() {
    console.log(sha1());
}
```

Comment: and pls do me one more help .how can i return the value to log_sha1 and store in variable.

Comment: @SagarGopale at this moment how can get both value

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(()=>{
sha1();
},5000);
```

Please make sure the function is in a callback.A setTimeout always has a callback attached to it, to make sure it works fine.I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Wrapping a function around `sha1()` which does nothing except call `sha1` is pointless. It doesn't change anything practical. It just makes it marginally slower and harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You code is fine, its just that the two `console.log(sha1());` statements execute it immediately. As the parenthesis after `sha1` causes it to execute.
You can either remove these two `console.log(sha1());` statements or change them to `console.log(sha1);`

Comment: if a replace console.log(sha1()) with console.log(sha1) then i am getting error like tihs on console -[Function: sha1]

Comment: Then try by removing this `console.log(sha1())`. This scenario is working fine on my side.

Comment: could u please share your code ? may be it will help me

Comment: Changing them to `console.log(sha1);` will mean that the **function** is logged **immediately** instead of the functions return value.

Comment: The intention was to not execute the function. @Quentin's answer is much more comprehensive.